# Create Folder for Each File in Recursive Directory, Placing File in Folder

Tags: bash, macos, loops, directory, nested

Create Folder for Each File in Recursive Directory, Placing File in Folder

On MacOS, so far I have...

```
for file in $(ls -R); do 
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then mkdir "${file%.*}"; mv "$file" "${file%.*}"; fi; 
done
```

This operates correctly on the top level of the nested folder, but does nothing with lower levels.

To isolate the error, I tried this instead, operating on rtf files . .

```
for i in $(ls -R);do
    if [ $i = '*.rtf' ];then
        echo "I do something with the file $i"
    fi
done
```

This hangs, so I simplified to . .

```
for i in $(ls -R); do echo "file is $i" done
```

That hangs also, so I tried . .

```
for i in $(ls -R); do echo hello
```

That hangs also.

`ls -R` works to provide a recursive list of all files.

Suggestions appreciated !!

Comment: To get some useful hints add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script and then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: You have too many errors really to list in comments. A few: 1) Use `**/*.rtf` to recursively loop over a tree of files; 2) Single quotes `'*.rtf'` will produce a fixed string - not a wild card; 3) Don't loop over `$(ls)`; 4) If looping with a `for` loop, use a glob; 5) If looping over a list of lines (which is what `$(something)` use a `while` loop. 6) Better still to use a `while` loop over a process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `ls` in scripts. It is meant to show output interactively. Although the newish GNU `ls` version has some features/options for shell parsing, not sure about on a Mac though.

Now using `find` with the `sh` shell.

```
find . -type f -name '*.rtf' -execdir sh -c '
  for f; do mkdir -p -- "${f%.*}" && mv -v -- "$f" "${f%.*}"; done' _ {} +
```

---

For whatever reason `-execdir` is not available, one can use `-exec`

```
find . -type f -name '*.rtf' -exec sh -c '
  for f; do mkdir -p -- "${f%.*}" && mv -v -- "$f" "${f%.*}" ; done' _ {} +
```

- See [Understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: Thanks all for responding -- so quickly !!
Good to know the difference between single and double quotes, as they are parsed by bash interpreter.
In the end, I used the last option offered above, for cases where execdir isn't available. Not sure if that's a MacOS thing, but regular exec seems to work fine.
I looked up the difference between bash and "sh." Apparently bash is sh ?!?
Usually, I put the shebang at the top, but again, this worked fine.

Comment: I looked up the difference between bash and "sh." Apparently bash is sh ?!?
Usually, I put the shebang at the top, but again, this worked.

I know there's a couple ways to end a find exec . . with {} \+ or {} \;
If I'm not mistaken, using the plus sign sends all the operands to exec at once, 
which can cause choking if there's enough of them, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

I tried coding this in python, but dealing with the difference in level between parent and child in the middle of an os.walk was very tricky . . bash was more straightforward, in this instance.

Comment: Again, thanks all for useful feedback !!

Comment: Nope, the `+`  sign will process as much as it can while avoiding [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) It DOES NOT send/process EVERYTHING until it chokes up..., Also `bash != sh`

Answer (score 0):

Given this file structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── 123
│   └── test_2.rtf
├── bar
│   ├── 456
│   │   └── test_1.rtf
│   └── 789
└── foo
```

There are two common ways to find all the `.rtf` files in that tree. The first (and most common) is to use `find`:

```
while IFS= read -r path; do 
    echo "$path"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.rtf")
```

Prints:

```
./bar/456/test_1.rtf
./123/test_2.rtf
```

The second common way is to use a recursive glob. This is not a POSIX way and is only found in more recent shells such as Bash, zsh, etc:

```
shopt -s globstar            # In Bash, this enables recursive globs
                             # In zsh, this is not required
for path in **/*.rtf; do 
    echo "$path"
done 
# same output
```

Now that you have the loop to find the files, you can modify the files found.

The first issue you will run across is that you cannot have two files with the same name in a single directory; a directory is just a type of file. So you will need to proceed this way:

1. Find all the files with their paths;
2. Create a `tmp` name and create a sub-directory with that temp name;
3. Move the found file into the temp directory;
4. Rename the temp directory to the found file name.

Here is a Bash (or zsh that is default on MacOS) script to do that:

```
shopt -s globstar              # remove for zsh
for p in **/*.rtf; do 
    [ -f "$p" ] || continue    # if not a file, loop onward
    tmp=$(uuidgen)             # easy temp name -- not POSIX however
    fn="${p##*/}"              # strip the file name from the path
    path_to="${p%/*}"          # get the path without the file name
    mkdir "${path_to}${tmp}"   # use temp name for the directory 
    mv "$p" "${path_to}$tmp"   # move the file to that directory
    mv "${path_to}$tmp" "$p"   # rename the directory to the path
done
```

And the result:

```
.
├── 123
│   └── test_2.rtf
│       └── test_2.rtf
├── bar
│   ├── 456
│   │   └── test_1.rtf
│   │       └── test_1.rtf
│   └── 789
└── foo
```

Comment: Thanks to all who took the time to respond. I got side tracked and will look over these answers.